# Randomly getting Cloud Storage Error: UNAUTHORIZED

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Today, I started receiving this error for, what I can tell, no reason. This isn't a consistent error. It randomly started today. It was working perfectly yesterday, and for weeks without any error.

All I have in the file is `file_get_contents()`.

I've been using the same code for `get_image.php` for a while and I have never received this error until now.

Does anyone know why this would be happening randomly and not consistently?

```
[20/Feb/2015:10:53:53 -0800] "POST /get_image HTTP/1.1" 200 149 - - "website.com" ms=296 cpu_ms=86 cpm_usd=0.000017 pending_ms=160 instance=<string> app_engine_release=1.9.18

W 13:53:53.815 PHP Warning:  Cloud Storage Error: UNAUTHORIZED in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/ext/cloud_storage_streams/CloudStorageReadClient.php on line 310
W 13:53:53.815 PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(gs://bucket/image/page_1.png): failed to open stream: "\google\appengine\ext\cloud_storage_streams\CloudStorageStreamWrapper::stream_open" call failed in /base/data/home/apps/..../get_image.php on line 10
```

---

### EDIT: For anyone looking for updates to this issue, [go to this bug report](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11695).

Add this to your code as a temporary fix for the time being as per Stuart Langley's post.

```
apc_delete('_ah_app_identity_:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only');
apc_delete('_ah_app_identity_:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write');
```

Comment: I've been getting the same issue since the 1.9.18 deployment yesterday - I have been able to resolve it temporarily by terminating all running instances, and letting GAE start new ones, but the issue returns several hours later.

Comment: I've got this issue also. But it is not random. It is for all file request.

Comment: Can you file a bug report? https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/FilingIssues?tm=3

Comment: I already did @StuartLangley https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11695&q=Cloud%20Storage%20Error%3A%20UNAUTHORIZED&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log

Comment: Same issue here.  My application was running no problem for many months up until Feb 19 when it starting getting these errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Stuart, the bug has been fixed. You shouldn't *randomly* receive this error anymore for no reason.